# How to download all images under one specific node in Scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy, I want to download all images under one node, for example, here is the web page:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<div class="A">
    <div class="A1">
        <div class="A2">
            <img original="a1.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A3">
        <img original="a2.png"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="B">
    <div class="B1">
        <div class="B2">
            <img original="b1.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="B3">
        <img original="b2.png"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to download all images (I need to find the original urls for these images) under class="A" but not class="B", and under class="A" we have a1.png and a2.png, they are at different levels (the number of level is uncertain).

Is there any way to target one attribute under one specific node using XPATH (something like //div[@class="A"]/**/img ) ?

or is there any solution in Scrapy?

Answer (score 2):

Using the following XPath to select all `img` nodes that are descendants of a `div` node with class `A`:

```
//div[@class="A"]//img
```

**[Demo](http://xpathfiddle.net/T9ZNMJ)**

The `//` matches descendants, as opposed to `/`, which matches direct children.

Comment: I think the demo link is dead...?